# Ignore fields from specific request in Spring-boot

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

i'm using Spring Boot REST Web Services and Angular 5 as a frontend, well i have model class for hibernate like this :

```
@Entity
public class Title {
        private Integer id;
        private String name;
        private Date releaseDate;
        private Time runtime;
        private String storyline;
        private String picture;
        private String rated;
        private String type;
        private Double rating;
        private Integer numberOfVotes;
        private Timestamp inserted;
        private Set<Genre> genres = new HashSet<>();
        private List<TitleCelebrity> titleCelebrities;
        private List<TitleMedia> titleMedia;

        // Basic getters and setter

        @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
        @JoinTable(name = "title_genre", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "title_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "genre_id") })
        public Set<Genre> getGenres() {
            return genres;
        }

        public void setGenres(Set<Genre> genres) {
            this.genres = genres;
        }

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "title", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        public List<TitleCelebrity> getTitleCelebrities() {
            return titleCelebrities;
        }

        public void setTitleCelebrities(List<TitleCelebrity> titleCelebrities) {
            this.titleCelebrities = titleCelebrities;
        }

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "title", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        public List<TitleMedia> getTitleMedia() {
            return titleMedia;
        }

        public void setTitleMedia(List<TitleMedia> titleMedia) {
            this.titleMedia = titleMedia;
        }
    }
```

And here's my REST controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("titles")
@CrossOrigin(origins = {"http://localhost:4200"})
public class TitleController {

    private TitleService titleService;

    @Autowired
    public void setTitleService(TitleService titleService) {
        this.titleService = titleService;
    }

    // Api to get all the movies ordered by release date
    @GetMapping("movies")
    public List<Title> getAllMoviesOrderByReleaseDateDesc() {
        return this.titleService.findByTypeOrderByReleaseDateDesc("movie");
    }

    @GetMapping("movies/{id}")
    public Title findById(@PathVariable Integer id) {
        return this.titleService.findById(id);
    }

}
```

What i want is when i make a request to the first method '/movies' i don't want the collection of titleMedia, but if i make a request to the second method '/movies/id' i want the collection of titleMedia.
of course the annotation `@JsonIgnore` will ignore the collection whatever the request is.

Comment: You should just wrap the response. Include the list in the wrapper if you want it and exclude it if you don't :)

Comment: i'm a spring boot newbie, is there any resources of how can achieve that ? thanks @DaisyDay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Various options:

1. In the method where you don't want the collection, put the list into the variable and then loop through it setting the collection to null.
2. Create a new object that extends title and in that new object put the field again 
   @JsonIgnore
   private List titleMedia;
   This should ignore it how you want. You can use a lambda to steam through the list building a list of the subclass by casting from it before returning it.
3. Create a new object with all the fields except the one you don't want that has a constructor that takes the Title object then laboriously sets all of those fields from the incoming title object.

You could do one of the above in the service layer, although my preferred option, which is the jsonignore in the subclass, should probably be done in the web layer.